# Flipping day and month in MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column called `subscription_start` where the data looks as follows:

```
subsciption_start
1/1/2020
13/1/2020
20/9/2020
```

I should also note that it's currently stored as a `STRING` and not `DATETIME` for obvious reasons (database won't accept `DATETIME` when 20 is the first number because it's expecting only 1 through 12)

I am trying to flip around the second number and the first number, so I can then put it in a proper `DATETIME` format where the end result looks like this:

```
subscription_start
01-01-2020
01-13-2020
09-20-2020
```

So what I'm looking for is two-fold: Flip around the numbers and put it in a more proper `DATETIME` format.

Comment: Another good example why storing DATE (or TIMESTAMP) values in a `text` column is a really bad idea. Do you have a chance to fix that broken design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best use `to_date` to parse the string and convert it to a `date` in one go:

```
SELECT to_date('20/9/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY');

  to_date   
------------
 2020-09-20
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.  Store the date as a proper format:

```
select to_char(subscription_start, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Or better yet, fix the data!

```
alter table t alter subscription_start type date using to_date(subscription_start, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Don't store date as strings!

Comment: Got an error for the first one:

`ERROR: function to_char(text, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Also concerning your second solution, let's assume I don't have the ability to alter tables

Comment: @gooponyagrinch . . . Interesting.  You accepted an equivalent answer posted a minute after mine.

Answer (score 0):

This would convert the varchar column to datetime in the format as is

`CONVERT(datetime, Subscription_Start, 103)`